# What does `@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data` do and is it necessary?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I got an auto-generated override like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

The `@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data` part looks curious and I'm not sure if it's necessary for it to exist. Does Android Studio need `@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable` to properly function?

Comment: I don't know about android studio (thats why i wrote this here), but usually its not necessary.
its marking that this field could be null, so if you write `data.something` the editor will show a warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to add `@Nullable` annotation in this method. This is just to let the programmer know that `data` could be `null` in some point. This is helpful also for the compiler, if you add the `@Nullable` and you don't check if it's null the compiler might warn you that you could get a `NullPointerException`.

### Edit

Perhaps this [`Annotating Type Arguments And Type Parameters`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#annotating-type-arguments-and-type-parameters) helps you to understand the difference. (*this is only for kotlin*)

Also there's the two types :

1.- [`Jetbrains Annotations`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html#notnull)

2.- [`Android Annotations`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations)

But roughly is because if you use the jetbrains it will warn you on *intelIJ* IDEs, for instance if you run a lint code via terminal it won't warn you, and the android one it will warn you even if you run it on pipelines, lint, etc.

So perhaps is better to use `androidx.annotation.Nullable` instead, that is more precise.

Comment: i'm actually asking why there are two nullables, I basically know what it does on its own but not why they thought it's a reasonable default to add two of them (one from androidx annotations and one from jetbrains annotations)

Comment: well, the only other information I feel is essential is if the androidx annotations are recognized on the same level as the jetbrains ones, but a quick check reveals they are. Your answer was kind of problematic for me to understand but I guess it contains that info, so ok.